# Help me to avoid multiple inheritance aka. help me to get proper oo design

Tags: design-patterns, oop, inheritance

I have two classes  LightA and LightB. I have the source code of LightB but not that of LightA. I  extended  LightB with LightDimDip. ie `LightDimDip:extends LightB`. Now I need to apply DimDip feature to lightB also.

Can any one suggest good OOP design.

Once again I remind you people that I cannot modify LightA.

Comment: I suggest you start with good class names. LightA, LightB, and LightDimDip doesn't tell anybody what they're for!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do the lights have a common interface? In which case I guess you could use the decorator pattern here

```
interface ILight { int GetIntensity() }
class LightA : ILight { int GetIntentisy(){ return 10; } }
class LightB : ILight { int GetIntensity(){ return 15; } }

class DimLight : ILight {
     public DimLight(ILight inner){}

     //Add behaviour inner
     int GetIntensity(){ return inner.GetIntensity() / 2; }
}

ILight dimLightA = new DimLight(new LightA())
ILight dimLightB = new DimLight(new LightB())
```

Then you can put the light behaviour in the DimLight class and apply it to any class which implements ILight.

Comment: The question says that the LightA class is not modifiable at this point.

Comment: @Whiskey-Tango-Foxtrot which is why I asked if there was a common interface in the first line of the response.

Comment: I have a root class (NSobject)